# Unbound method error in my code

Tags: python-2.7, python-2.x

```
Class test:

    a=10
    b=20
    Def c(self,a,b):
        Return a+b
Print test.a
#10
Print test.b
#20
Print test.c(1,2)

#Error unbound method c()
```

Plz point out were I am going wrong I am beginner in terms of using classes

Sorry for the upper cases in my code .I had to type it out on my tiny mobile screen.

Comment: You misspelled `class`, `def`, `print`, and `return`. And you tagged both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x. Which is it?

Comment: You need to create a new instance of `test` to use a method on it.

Comment: It's not Python 3, that's for sure

Comment: Interesting that you got an unbound method error instead of just a type error informing you that you passed in the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: @smarx. That is true, but you can also call the method on the class and pass in an explicit reference for self.

Comment: Sure, or you can just make it a class method, since it doesn't make use of `self` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You have tried to access method inside class directly.

To call method inside class need to create instance of class

following programming will work

```
class Test:
    a = 10    # class variable
    b = 20    # class variable
    def c(self,a,b):
            return a+b

print Test.a
print Test.b
obj = Test()
print obj.c(1,2) #3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# class is lowercase
# class names are by convention uppercase (Test)
class Test:
    # def is lowercase
    def c(self, a, b):
        # return is lowercase
        return a + b

# Create a new instance of the Test class
test = Test()

print test.c(1, 2)  # prints 3
```